Bug with pst-solides3d and prisme object?
I’m trying to draw a simple prism but with an axis different from z. I face 2 problems: 1/ first axe=2 0 2 produces a translation (whereas axe=0 2 2 gives the right result); 2/ hidden and visible faces are not draw correctly.
Any ideas?
% compiler avec lualatex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-solides3d}


\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(3,3)
    \psset{viewpoint=10
-40 10,Decran=15}
\psSolid[
object=prisme,
base=0 0 0 3 4 3 4 0, axe=2 0 2,
h=3,
action=draw*,
linecolor=red,
]%
\axesIIID(0,0,0)(3,3,3)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}



looks like a bug and need some investigation into pst-solides3d.pro
